# Multiple INNER JOIN Query does not return a Response

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to run the following sql query on my node.js server:

```
export const loginGuard = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password, isAdmin } = req.body;
    if (isAdmin === 0) {
      connection.query(
      SELECT guard.guardID, guard.firstName, guard.middleName, guard.lastName, guard.email, guard.password, guard.phone, guard.dob, guard.gender, guard.emergencyContact, guard.isAdmin,guard.isGuard, guard.isCompany AS guard, guardaddress.guardAddressId, guardaddress.state, guardaddress.city, guardaddress.postalCode AS guardaddress, document.documentID, document.four82, document.PCR, document.CPR, document.CrowdControl, document.License, document.Firearms, document.FirstAid, document.FirstAid, document.MediCare, document.Passport, document.ResponsibleAlcohol, document.Visa, document.WhiteCard, document.YellowCard, document.WorkingWithChildren AS document otherdocs.otherDocsId, otherdocs.name, otherdocs.document AS otherdocs, bank.bankID, bank.name, bank.accountTitle, bank.accountNo, bank.bsb, bank.abn AS bank, shift.shiftID, shift.startTime, shift.endTime, shift.date AS shift 
      FROM guard 
      INNER JOIN guardaddress ON guard.guardID = guardaddress.fk_guard 
      INNER JOIN document ON document.fk_guard = guard.guardID 
      INNER JOIN bank ON bank.guard_id = guard.guardID 
      INNER JOIN otherdocs ON otherdocs.fk_guard = guard.guardID 
      INNER JOIN shift ON shift.fk_guard = guard.guardID 
      WHERE guard.email='${email}' && shift.date > '${Date.now()},
        function (err, rows) {
          console.log(rows); // trying to console rows; returns "undefined"
          if (!err && rows[0].password === password) {
            const accessToken = jwt.sign(
              {
                id: rows[0].guardID,
                isAdmin: rows[0].isAdmin,
                isGuard: rows[0].isGuard,
                isCompany: rows[0].isCompany,
              },
              SECRET,
              {
                expiresIn: "3d",
              }
            );
            res.status(201).json({
              success: true,
              message: "Guard Logged In!",
              profile: {
                guard: {
                  guardID: rows[0].guardID,
                  firstName: rows[0].firstName,
                  middleName: rows[0].middleName,
                  lastName: rows[0].lastName,
                  email: rows[0].email,
                  password: rows[0].password,
                  phone: rows[0].phone,
                  dob: rows[0].dob,
                  gender: rows[0].gender,
                  emergencyContact: rows[0].emergencyContact,
                },
              accessToken,
            });
          } else {
            res
              .status(404)
              .json({ success: false, message: "Guard Not Found!" });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

But i don't get anything in response, i tried running the same query in MySQL workbench and it works. Maybe it is a syntax error for the query or i might be missing something in the code. I am not sure of the mistake i am making.

Comment: The fact that you've ran the query directly on the DB server means that the query is valid, I guess. The next step is to check the next layer, which is the code invoking the query. You need to share some of that, so we can help. Off the top of my head I can think of some potential issues cropping up from the fact that it's async code and you're not `await`ing, or not handling the Promise properly with `.then().catch()`.

Comment: if the query is working in workbench, then the problem is not with the query but with your code, and you are going to need to show your code.

Comment: @AndreiMustata i am running other SQL queries also without any async/await, these are not asynchronous.  As for the next(), the query is singularly called on a route. I will share the complete code for better reference.

Comment: @MushoodHanif what is `connection`, what lib are you using, what is the signature of the callback? Could it be that the arguments are the other way around?